# If $w$ is an imaginary fifth root of 2 and $x=w+w^{2}$ then what is the value of $x^{5}-10x^{2} -10x$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried to solve this problem by doing this way : $( x-w)^{5} =\left( w^{2}\right)^{5}$ and got this equation $x^{5}-5wx^{4}+10w^{2}x^{3}-10w^{3}x^{2}+5w^{4}x=6$ but I don't know how to proceed further. Would someone please help me here.

Comment: note that $x^5=2$

Comment: Shouldn't it be 4 in the RHS?

Comment: To the title: $2$ has no imaginary fifth roots.  It has four complex fifth roots...

Comment: I brought the -w^5 term on right hand side of the equation and got 6 there @Ishraaq Parvez

Comment: @ShiveeGupta You're early.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
(\omega + \omega^2)^5 
    &= \omega^5 + 5 \omega^6 + 10 \omega^7 + 10 \omega^8 + 5 \omega^9 + \omega^{10}  \\
    &= 2 + 10 \omega + 20 \omega^2 + 20 \omega^3 + 10 \omega^4 + 4  \text{,}  \\
-10(\omega + \omega^2)^2
    &= -10 \omega^2 - 20 \omega^3 - 10 \omega^4  \\
-10(\omega + \omega^2)
    &= -10 \omega - 10 \omega^2  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Recalling that since $w$ is a fifth root of $2$ we have that $w^5 = 2$, we notice that
\begin{align*}
x^5 - 10x^2 -10x & =\left(w + w^2\right)^5 - 10\left(w + w^2\right)^2 - 10\left(w + w^2\right) \\
&= \underbrace{w^{10}}_{\color{blue}{4}} + 5 w^9 + 10 w^8 + 10 w^7 + 5 w^6 + \underbrace{w^5}_{\color{blue}{2}} - 10 w^4 - 20 w^3 - 20 w^2 - 10 w\\
&= 5 w^9 + 10 w^8 + 10 w^7 + 5 w^6  - 10 w^4 - 20 w^3 - 20 w^2 - 10 w + \color{blue}{6}
\end{align*}
Now, what do we do with the expression besides the $6$? If we factor it we see we can re-write it as
$$
5  w(w+1)\left(w^2 + w +1\right)\left(\color{purple}{w^5 -2}\right)+ \color{blue}{6}
$$
But since we know that $w^5 =2$, this implies that $w^5 -2 = 2-2 = 0$, so in fact, the whole rest of the expression has a $0$ multiplying it! Hence, everything besides the $6$ gets canceled and you can conclude that
$$
x^5 - 10x^2 -10x = 6
$$

Comment: Writing $(\omega + \omega^2)^5=\omega^5(1+\omega)^5=2(1+\omega)^5$ will simplify this a bit more.